# Running c++ console application shows only "Press any key to continue."

Tags: windows-7, codeblocks, codelite

I am using CodeLite and code block to learn c++. When I run any c++ program, it only shows "Press any key to continue." I downloaded MinGW compiler and also llvm-clang compiler. I select both one by one and run program. 
It only shows "Press any key to continue". Can anyone help me understand why it happens?

Edit:1 // Added Code

This is my sample program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
     std::cout << "Hello, World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Edit:2 // For more clarification

My program runs perfectly in Xcode. But I have a problem in Windows 7 32 bit with CodeLite and code block. Consider that I have installed Compiler and also made appropriate settings suggested by code block and CodeLite website.

Why does it only show "Press any key to continue."? Is there any problem with some setting or did I forget to set an environment variable or something else?

Comment: Please include a short code sample of a program that shows no output.

Comment: What ever you write and run it only shows "Press any key to continue." I tried many different program.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Create a simple "Hello World" application, verify that it still tells you "Press any key to continue.", and then post that source code here. That way we can see if it is something in the code.

Comment: Without code we can only speculate...

Comment: Have you already tried compiling and running from the command line?

Comment: `#define merge(a,b) b##a` To be honest, I'm not sure what that does. What happens if you take out the merge and compare and just print hello world?

Comment: Now friends look at code. I hope you understand the problem.

Comment: Isn't `##` limited to concatenation of literal strings?

Comment: @Glapa Code is prefect. Whatever i write code and run it only shows "Press any key to continue."

Comment: Try this code, see if you still see only the "Press any key to continue." http://ideone.com/6W2WQh

Comment: @RyanP Please check it now tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching, i find the correct solution.
The main problem was of 32 bit operation system. As the application suggest it works for 32 bits but i had the problem.
So i format my windows 7 32 bit and installed windows 7 64 bit os and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This could happen if your executable path is not correct.

For CodeLite check the "Executable to Run/Debug" path and "Working Directory" path in your project settings.

For CodeBlocks check the "Execution working dir" and "Objects output dir" in your project properties - build targets.

The default setting should work without problems.